# XML regex not allowing ampersand

Tags: c#, regex, xsd

We have following regex

```
(^\S+([0-9a-zA-Z\-\?:\(\)\.,&apos;\+\s].\S+)*$)
```

XML schema interpretation of this regex does not allow for ampersand (`&`) anywhere in the text but in the .NET interpretation, it is allowed.

Please help with rewriting it so that it will behave the same in XML  schema validation and .NET validation.

We have tried to integrate something like this `^[^&]*$` but without success.

Regex should disable the use of characters that is not a-z A-Z / - ? : ( ) . , ‘ + and disable the use of slash "/" at the beginning and end of line and double slash "//" within the line. It should not contain repeated whitespace inside the text and leading or trailing whitespaces.

Following texts should not be valid either in XML schema validation and in .NET regex validation:

```
Dlhy & testovaci nazov
Dlhy&Testovaci nazov
Dlhy &Testovaci nazov
Dlhy& Testovaci nazov
Dlhy  Testovaci nazov
```

This is valid

```
Dlhy a: 'Testovaci, (nazov.) /? +
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this regex

In free spacing mode (https://regex101.com/r/uXyPly/1):

```
(?x)                     # turns on free spacing mode
^                        # start of line
(?!\/|\h)                # disable / and space at start of line
(?!.*\h\h|.*\/\/)        # disable double space or /
[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+\h]+ # allows specified character set
[a-zA-Z\-?:()\.,'+]      # space and / not allowed at end
$                        # end of line
```

normal mode (https://regex101.com/r/Z4K9zm/1):

```
^(?!\/|\h)(?!.*\h\h|.*\/\/)[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+\h]+[a-zA-Z\-?:()\.,'+]$
```

NOTE:

1. I excluded negative lookbehinds as you suggested in your comment.
2. I used `\h` instead of `\s` to ensure horizontal whitespace (`\s` can also capture linebreaks)

Comment: I just corrected it a but to handle whitespace instead of just space: ^(?!\/|[\s])(?!.*[\s][\s]|.*\/\/)[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+ ]+(?<!\/|[\s])$

Comment: I found a problem of compatibility with (?<! so I edited it as following ^(?!\/|[\s])(?!.*[\s][\s]|.*\/\/)[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+ ]+([^\/]|[^\S])$ but the problem is, that it accepts single space at the end of the string. Can you advice how to solve that?

Comment: maybe replace `([^\/]|[^\S])` with `[a-zA-Z\-?:()\.,'+]`? this says: last token may be any element that was specified before (`[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+ ]`) but space and `/` are not allowed now. Also maybe use `[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+\s]` instead of `[a-zA-Z\/\-?:()\.,'+ ]`.

Comment: as for your problem - i think you have an accidental double negation: [^\S] means not a character that is not a space -> any space character. 
---
If you find this answer satisfactory please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: unfortunately I need the regex to function in XML validation and so I can not use lookahead or lookbehind constructs. I have this version now [0-9a-zA-Z\-?:().,+&apos;]{1}([0-9a-zA-Z/\-?:().,+ &apos;])*[0-9a-zA-Z\-?:().,+&apos;]+   but it enables double spaces within the string which it should not, but I'll probably have to live with it

Answer (score 0):

With .NET you could match 1 or more spaces or forward slashes but not double occurrences using a capture group and a backreference.

The outer repeating group can be an [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>` to prevent some backtracking in case there is no match.

In case you want to match whitespace chars (including newlines), you can replace   with `\s`

```
^[a-zA-Z?:().,'+-]+(?>(?:([ /])(?!\1))+[a-zA-Z?:().,'+-]+)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z?:().,'+-]+` Match 1 or more of the allowed chars
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `([ /])(?!\1)` Capture either a space or `/` in group 1, and using a negative lookahead `(?!` assert that the next character is not the same as the captured one using a backreference `\1`
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times
  - `[a-zA-Z?:().,'+-]+` Match 1 or more of the allowed chars
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RE9I3w/1).

Comment: Thank you but the problem is, that it would not be validated only in .net but also in pure XML so I can not use start of string and end of string flags ...

Comment: @zdenok And you can also not use lookarounds?

Comment: @zdenok Try it like this `(?:[0-9a-zA-Z\-?:()+.,‘']+|&apos;)(?:(?: /?|/ ?)(?:[0-9a-zA-Z\-?:()+.,‘']+|&apos;))*` https://regex101.com/r/gaVp6D/1